# Where are my old (previous) iCloud files after upgrading to OS X 10.10 Yosemite Beta 1?

Tags: icloud, textedit, macos, library

I previously had about 200 .txt files saved in iCloud via TextEdit.

After installing the Yosemite (10.10) Beta, **there is now a folder hierarchie in iCloud**, and **all my previous files seem to have disappeared**.

I have looked in /Library/Mobile Documents -- they're not there.

To be clear, I'm not complaining! I'd just like to find a way to **import my previous iCloud files into the new iCloud**.

*[edit] I have also tried showing hidden files and looking through the Library with no success.*

Comment: There is an answer to this but I am not sure I can give it here??

Comment: You should ask your question at : https://devforums.apple.com/community/mac/betas

Comment: I'm not a developer, just an enthusiast. Therefore I can't sign in to devforums.apple.com. I have read the two links above about why one should not ask about not-publicly-released software, and I will just point out that a) I am in no sense ranting, b) I was clear in asking the question that this is specific to an early beta (there is no risk of confusion for future visitors) and c) software is updated all the time and many "canonical" answers will become out of date unless they refer to a specific software version.

Comment: Then I can only suggest maybe you look the App itself rather than the file system.. and let logic prevail

Comment: I'd just like to apologize for the testy tone of my previous comment. I really appreciate that people with much more experience on this site make an effort to keep it well organized.

Comment: I did look around at the app package contents, and also within TextEdit (for a long time!) with no luck.